# Postfix add header to outbound emails from a single host

Tags: email, postfix

Situation:
I’ve got an app that sends weekly emails to about 30 friends. I can’t modify the app. I want it to have a list-unsubscribe header. No other emails come from this IP to my mail server that shouldn’t have this header.

Can I have postfix add the list-unsubscribe header to all mail from 192.168.x.y before it sends them to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using the PREPEND action for postfix header_checks https://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html. Example of how to do it can be seen (at the time of writing) [here](https://www.allerstorfer.at/postfix-add-custom-header/) (if not when you read this, just search for 'postfix prepend example').